# How to merge two or more cells in table with react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I can't find any information in documentation of react-admin how to merge cells in table? is it possibe to do it? any examples?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use a `function field` and insert the variables that you need.

As seen in the documentation where they mix `firstName` and `lastName`: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#functionfield

You can see it working in the react-admin demo, in the reviews or the customers section.